# Why Google Chrome loads JPG instead of Avif and WebP?

Tags: html, image

I'm scratching my head why Google Chrome loads JPG instead of Avif and WebP?
Here's my code:

```
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="/assets/img/768w.avif" type="image/avif">
<source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="/assets/img/768w.webp" type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="/assets/img/576w.avif" type="image/avif">
<source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="/assets/img/576w.webp" type="image/webp">
<img src="/assets/img/768w.jpg" alt="image" width="100%" height="auto" class="img-fluid" decoding="async" loading="lazy">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all of your sources are specified for screens smaller than 991px – I guess you are loading page on larger device (or window width) so only default src fits the query.
The second mistake is expecting filename should be recognized as media query. I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="/assets/img/576w.avif 576w, /assets/img/768w.avif 768w" type="image/avif">
```

This means "while screen is smaller than 991px use avif. According to your [screen pixel density and current width](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-img-srcset) will be loaded one of two images".
Same for webp. You also need to specify sources for screens larger than 991px.
Take a look at this [example](https://codepen.io/pepelsbey/pen/aQLvGJ/)